# how can i parse this complex json nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i am trying to parse json

```
    request(requestOptions,(err,res,body)=>{

      for(var i in body){
        console.log(body.data[0].quote.USD.price)
      }

  })
```

and the json is something like

```
{ status: {something},
  data: [{
          id:1,
     name:'Bitcoin',
     symbol:'BTC',
     slug:'bitcoin',
     circulating_supply:17400325,
     total_supply:17400325,
     max_supply:21000000,
     date_added:'2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z',
     num_market_pairs:6618,
     tags:[
        Array
     ],
     cmc_rank:1,
     last_updated:'2018-11-30T11:00:28.000Z',
     quote:[
        Object
     ]
        }]
}
```

quote object is :

```
{ USD:
{ price: 4071.55349237,
 volume_24h: 5966638087.9657,
 percent_change_1h: -3.18515,
 percent_change_24h: -6.66359,
 percent_change_7d: -5.74611,
 market_cap: 70846354022.12302,
 last_updated: '2018-11-30T11:03:22.000Z' } }
```

"there is two json object one i mentioned and other one is duplicate of above json".

```
{ status:{ },
   data:[ ]
}
```

i run above code it gives me this output:

1
Bitcoin
BTC
4030.51947765
1
Bitcoin
BTC
4030.51947765

kindly help me how i can get all "id","name", " symbol", "price" of object, and save it to one array.

Comment: `console.log(body.data[0].id)
        console.log(body.data[0].name)
        console.log(body.data[0].symbol)`

Comment: Is body.data[0].quote an array of objects?  If so use `body.data[0].quote[0].USD.price`

Comment: it is a perameter of request() function

Comment: In your JSON string you have `quote:[ Object ]` - that looks like an array of objects but since it's not the actual JSON, just what you posted, I can't be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
let mydata = { status: "something",
      data: [{
              id:1,
         name:'Bitcoin',
         symbol:'BTC',
         slug:'bitcoin',
         circulating_supply:17400325,
         total_supply:17400325,
         max_supply:21000000,
         date_added:'2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z',
         num_market_pairs:6618,
         tags:[
            "Something"
         ],
         cmc_rank:1,
         last_updated:'2018-11-30T11:00:28.000Z',
         quote:
            { USD:
                { price: 4071.55349237,
                 volume_24h: 5966638087.9657,
                 percent_change_1h: -3.18515,
                 percent_change_24h: -6.66359,
                 percent_change_7d: -5.74611,
                 market_cap: 70846354022.12302,
                 last_updated: '2018-11-30T11:03:22.000Z' } }

            }]
    }
let myArray = []
mydata.data.map((o)=>{
    const { id, name, symbol } = o
    myArray.push({
        id,
        name,
        symbol,
        price : o.quote.USD.price
    })
})
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: `map` automatically creates a new array, so `myArray = data.map` also kills the `push`

Comment: map create difference instance of mydata,data. it has nothing to do with myarray.. myarray is totally different array

Answer (score 0):

Simply map it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-c1fwsf

```
const req = { 
  data: [
    {
     id:1,
     name:'Bitcoin',
     symbol:'BTC',
     slug:'bitcoin',
     circulating_supply:17400325,
     total_supply:17400325,
     max_supply:21000000,
     date_added:'2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z',
     num_market_pairs:6618,
     cmc_rank:1,
     last_updated:'2018-11-30T11:00:28.000Z',
     quote:[
        { 
          USD:
          { 
            price: 4071.55349237,
            volume_24h: 5966638087.9657,
            percent_change_1h: -3.18515,
            percent_change_24h: -6.66359,
            percent_change_7d: -5.74611,
            market_cap: 70846354022.12302,
            last_updated: '2018-11-30T11:03:22.000Z' 
          } 
        }
     ],
    },
     {
     id:2,
     name:'Litecoin',
     symbol:'LTC',
     slug:'litecoin',
     circulating_supply:17400325,
     total_supply:17400325,
     max_supply:21000000,
     date_added:'2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z',
     num_market_pairs:6618,
     cmc_rank:1,
     last_updated:'2018-11-30T11:00:28.000Z',
     quote:[
        { 
  USD:
  { 
    price: 221.55349237,
    volume_24h: 5966638087.9657,
    percent_change_1h: -3.18515,
    percent_change_24h: -6.66359,
    percent_change_7d: -5.74611,
    market_cap: 70846354022.12302,
    last_updated: '2018-11-30T11:03:22.000Z' 
  } 
}
     ]
  }]
}

const res = req.data.map(x => ({
  name: x.name,
  id: x.id,
  symbol: x.symbol,
  price: x.quote[0].USD.price,
}))

console.log(res)
```

[image: See!]

Comment: It's not the decimals, it's the number of significant digits.  If you multiply the bitcoin price by 100 mil (ie eliminate the decimal point) its 32-bit float representation is just as imprecise.

Comment: @mchl18 these three values i got already but due to duplicate of object which provided by "Api manufacturer " may be entire values or set of values which i want, but i cant. i mean "bitcoin set" "other coin" sets i cant get. but only one.

Comment: @rohai789 not sure what you mean with the last one?

Comment: see the updated code, it works on multiple currencies